# Error while compiling with clang: Exception specification is not available until end of class definition

Tags: c++, clang

There is an error while compiling c++ library with clang 800.0.38 on MacOS.

```
template<class T> struct _reference_base<T, int>
    {
      enum { rb_tag = 1 }; typedef T t;
      static inline t* deref(_stg_u& x, bool byptr) throw() { return reinterpret_cast<t*>(byptr ? x.p1 : &x); }
      static inline t* _drf_c(const unity* p) throw() { return deref(p->_data, p->isByPtr()); }
    };
```

On this line: `static inline t* _drf_c(const unity* p) throw() { return deref(p->_data, p->isByPtr()); }`

And this line:
`static inline t* deref(_stg_u& x, bool byptr) throw() { return reinterpret_cast<t*>(byptr ? x.p1 : &x); }`

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. The lib was written using c++11, so i need to activate c++11. I added cmake line

`set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)`

Comment: This is a CMake-only workaround which does no state what is the immediate cause for error.

Comment: Actually no. It means, it didn't compile because of c++11 was not enabled, that's the point.